# I am unable to form table in List<String> using struts 2 tags

Tags: java, struts2, iterator

i am using struts 2 and i am using iterator tag , when i used to iterate List i failed get the value and create table from collection , where value in List is dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please give more details. some code may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are creating `list<String>` in your action class which you are iterating in your jsp

```
public class IteratorAction extends ActionSupport{

    private List<String> list;

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setlist(List<String> list) {
        this.list= list;
    }

    public String execute() {

        list= new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("E");
        list.add("F");

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

you can use that list in your jsp like

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="list" status="listStatus">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="#listStatus.even == true">
      <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property/></td>
    </s:if>
    <s:elseif test="#listStatus.first == true">
      <td><s:property/> (This is first value) </td>
    </s:elseif>
    <s:else>
      <td><s:property/></td>
    </s:else>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

i hope this will help you if you have diffrent requirement lets us know with details only than some one can help you in best possible way

Comment: ya i had when i do like that i am receiving data one by one not like a table can u help me , where i am readying from List<String> Example
Rno 
Rname 
Not in table

Comment: @Mohan.N Can you explain what exact is your requirement as i am unable to understand

Comment: yes i will explain what i am actually doing , i am running dynamic query , so i cant expect what the result must be even i am not aware of column name and rows, i am getting the result so the query in list<String> with List<String> i am using using List<List<String>> so for every query there is would be result for in the form of List<String>, when i iterate the List<String> i cant form table for that query result ,i have used the above code but even i am not table , as my column are displaying like
A
B